# YouTube Android API seekToMillis() not working accurately

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

While using the `youtubePlayer.seekToMillis()` function, there is a seek delay of 2 seconds. Not exactly 2 seconds, but roughly so. Like if you try to seek any where between 10,000 milliseconds and 12,000 milliseconds (eg: 11,000 11,500, 11,550). The video will be started from 10,000 itself. If you give a value between 12,000 and 14,000 it goes to the 12,000 point.. and so on...

We are developing an app where a YouTube has to start from accurate the time specified. Hence this function is quite crucial for us.

```
youtubePlayer.seekToMillis(10000);
youtubePlayer.play();
```

Please show us some hints how we can start a video with the YouTube player from a precise starting time, if possible precisely to the millisecond.

Comment: I think that's what YouTube itself make, which you can't change.

Comment: Yes. But it cant be that youtube developers missed out a such an evident bug. I guess there should be some way out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug, **this is the standard behavior of a seekable-compressed video file**.

### Short and super-simplified explanation

A compressed video file is composed by a sequence of frames. There are two macro-types of frame, **full frames** (*F*) and **partial frames** (p*):

- *full frame*: contains the full real frame at a specific time (like a full JPEG image)
- *partial frame* is only a set of *differences* in relation to the previous frame, usually expressed as motion vectors.

**Raw video sequence:**

#### F F F F F F F F F F F F F F F F F F ... (eof)

**Compressed video sequence:**

#### F p p p p F p p p p F p p p p p F p p ... (eof)

A Compressed structure like this allows to create **smaller file** (because *partial frames* are smaller than *full frames*), but also introduces a silly problem: **it is not possible to start the playback directly from a partial frame** because, in order to decode it correctly, you will need do ascend until the first *full frame*!

> This is exactly the problem you are experiencing: you are seeking
>   to a specific time which is mapped on a *partial frame*, so you need to go back
>   to the nearest *full frame* and start the playback from there.

In a streming context like YouTube the problem is even more difficult because is header to trick this limitation using, for example, a fast forward approach.

As written above, this is a very simplified explanation. You can find more information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types).

Comment: If I fetch a high quality video from YouTube instead of a low quality one(which is what I am doing no), is this problem still likely to persist ? Or say is there any other way out of this?

Comment: @HarishMohanan I'm not sure about how YouTube handles the various format of the video but I can suppose that the lower quality version could have less key frames than the higher one. You can just try ;)